# RecursiveFilterIterator::accept filters ous directories called "0"

Tags: type-conversion, spl

I have this simple class:

```
class MyRecursiveFilterIterator extends RecursiveFilterIterator {

    public function accept() {
        $filename = $this->current()->getFilename();

        // Skip hidden files and directories.
        if ($filename[0] === '.') {
            return false;
        }

        return (string)$filename;
    }

}
```

And then I use it simply:

```
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::FOLLOW_SYMLINKS);
$filter = new MyRecursiveFilterIterator($directory);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($filter);
$files = array();
foreach ($iterator as $info) {
    $files[] = $info->getPathname();
}
var_dump($files);
```

The problem is that even though `RecursiveFilterIterator::accept` sometimes returns `string(1) "0"` it is interpreted as `false` and the directory is skipped.

How can I get this to work with directories named "0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `true` instead of the file name.